# Scrolling the custom views - Android

Tags: android, scrollview

Below is the image of the menu I need to make.

[image]

I have drawn the triangles using canvas in custom views. I also need to scroll this menu, when custom views are added in the scroll view it takes each View as a rectangular item not allowing the triangles to be drawn like this.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you must create 2 custom views, with different draws of triangles. Then in your `RelativeLayout` or another create those triangles and set the, negative `margin_top` value for correct presentation, like in my example:

[image]

So, now lets look at code.

Dont critic my code. It`s just example for you without true OOP structure :)

- ### CustomShapeLeft.class:

  ```
  /**
   * Created by gigamole on 07.02.15.
   */
  public class CustomShapeLeft extends RelativeLayout {
      Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

  int backgroundColor;
  int viewWidth; // width of parent(CustomShape layout)
  int viewHeight;

  public CustomShapeLeft(Context context) {
      super(context);
      this.setWillNotDraw(false);
  }

  public CustomShapeLeft(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      this.setWillNotDraw(false);

      TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[]{android.R.attr.background});
      this.backgroundColor = ((ColorDrawable) ta.getDrawable(0)).getColor();

      this.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
  }

  public CustomShapeLeft(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
      this.setWillNotDraw(false);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld) {
      super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

      viewWidth = xNew;
      viewHeight = yNew;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }

  Path path = new Path();
  Point[] points = new Point[3];

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.onDraw(canvas);

      paint.setColor(backgroundColor);
      paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

      points[0] = new Point(0, 0);
      points[1] = new Point(viewWidth, (viewHeight / 2));
      points[2] = new Point(0, (viewHeight));

      path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
      path.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
      path.lineTo(points[1].x, points[1].y);
      path.lineTo(points[2].x, points[2].y);
      path.close();

      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  public boolean isTouched(final float X, final float Y){
      final Polygon p = new Polygon(points);
      return p.contains(X, Y);
  }
  ```

  }

Method `isTouched()` need for know when the user tap on shape, but not on `View,` cause when on last, its problematic to take correct action, cause they lay down like layer-layer-layer system.

This method get the position of tap and calculate is on shape or not. In your way you will dont have `onClickListener`, just `onTouchListener`.

- ### CustomShapeRight.class:

They are almost similar, but different draw methods:

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        paint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        points[0] = new Point(viewWidth, 0);
        points[1] = new Point(0, (viewHeight / 2));
        points[2] = new Point(viewWidth, (viewHeight));

        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
        path.lineTo(points[1].x, points[1].y);
        path.lineTo(points[2].x, points[2].y);
        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
```

- ### Layout.xml:

  ```
  <null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeLeft
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:id="@+id/triangle_1"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:textSize="22dp"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:text="MEN"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

  </null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeLeft>

  <null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeRight
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:id="@+id/triangle_2"
      android:layout_marginTop="-36dp"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
      android:layout_below="@+id/triangle_1">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:textSize="22dp"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:text="HOME"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

  </null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeRight>

  <null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeLeft
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:id="@+id/triangle_3"
      android:layout_marginTop="-36dp"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
      android:layout_below="@+id/triangle_2">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:textSize="22dp"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:text="WOMEN"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

  </null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeLeft>

  <null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeRight
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:id="@+id/triangle_4"
      android:layout_marginTop="-36dp"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
      android:layout_below="@+id/triangle_3">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:textSize="22dp"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:text="ART"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

  </null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeRight>

  <null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeLeft
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:id="@+id/triangle_5"
      android:layout_marginTop="-36dp"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
      android:layout_below="@+id/triangle_4">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:textSize="22dp"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:text="KIDS"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

  </null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeLeft>

  <null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeRight
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:id="@+id/triangle_6"
      android:layout_marginTop="-36dp"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
      android:layout_below="@+id/triangle_5">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:textSize="22dp"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:text="MUSIC"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

  </null_anal.customshape.CustomShapeRight>
  ```

And in activity set them `onTouchListener()`:

```
CustomShapeRight customShapeRight = (CustomShapeRight) findViewById(R.id.triangle_6);
        customShapeRight.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (((CustomShapeRight)v).isTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)((CustomShapeRight) v).getChildAt(0)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

And all. I`d hope this will help you and with delete items "X" item in your layout you will deal with it alone. And thanks for cool question. Like it.

Comment: The main question was how to scroll these custom shapes .
i have used these kind of custom views in scroll view. For that i have to override onMeasure() method which takes only fixed height and width.

Comment: Man, just put my `RelativeLayout` to your `ScrollView`.